# Double Pointer and Local Scope Confusion

Tags: c, pointers, scope, dereference

I am taking a c programming course on Udemy and am quite confused when passing a double pointer into a function.  In the example, the instructor passes the address of a pointer as an argument to a function.  Then, he de-references that double pointer parameter in the function and sets it equal to the address of a local variable (a).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void foo(int **temp_ptr)
{
   int a = 5;
   *temp_ptr = &a;
}

int main()
{
   int *ptr = NULL;
   ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
   *ptr = 10;
   foo(&ptr);
   printf("%d\n", *ptr);

   return 0;
}
```

So, what we are doing here is changing the value of `ptr` to hold the address of `a`. Then, when we de-reference `ptr`, it should display the value of `5` and not `10`, since we changed the value of `ptr` to hold the address of `a`.

This is indeed correct: it displays 5 and not 10.

However, what doesn't make sense here is that the variable `a` is in the local scope of the `foo` function.  When we declare `a`, the memory allocated is put onto the stack frame; thus, when leaving the local scope of the function that memory is deleted and the frame is popped off of the stack. How can we still access that variable a with the `ptr` variable in the main function? Shouldn't that memory be completely wiped out?

Comment: Yes.  'de-references that double pointer parameter in the function and sets it equal to the address of a local variable' - he shouldn't make a habit of it:(

Comment: This code invokes *undefined behavior*, so making sense of it has little benefit. `printf("%d\n", *ptr);` in `main` dereferences a dangling pointer to a long-ago-destroyed `a` in a function call that is no longer active. Undefined behavior has the annoying tendency of appearing to 'work' when in reality it is not defined to do so. It may also *not* 'work'. It may format your boot volume. Address sanitizers can often catch these logical problems. And if your 'instructor' says this is ok, find a new prof; their head is firmly inserted in their own arse.

Comment: Udemy, eh? That instructor is incompetent.

Comment: Now you're scaring him with `format` @WhozCraig I remember my instructor telling me when I was a teenager, `don't touch that delete key`.

Comment: Hello All, Thanks for the comments. So what I was saying was correct that the memory of the stack should be completely wiped out and this is undefined behavior?  But sometimes undefined behavior works?

Comment: @karl-gardner there is no Stack in the C language.  Who told you there is a stack ?  The C language does not care about the stack.  It can also keep the variable in a register, in a memory address elsewhere outside the stack, etc.  Sometimes, it will keep  *temp_ptr* on the stack.

Comment: Yes, undefined behavior often works. That's one of the worst things about it.

Comment: Undefined behavior does seem to have a propensity of appearing to 'work' in your development environment, but dumping like a diarrhetic canine when run by your professors, or even worse, a paying customer. It is the single-most-often shortcoming of university language courses today. They stress language basics and algorithms, but they rarely stress the in-depth familiarity one needs to "know" that something will work because the formal language specification *says so*, and as-important, when it cannot be relied on because the same specification says there is no defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, when we de-reference `ptr`, it should display the value of 5

*Should* is incorrect.  `printf("%d\n", *ptr);` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as the address stored in `ptr` is invalid with the return of `foo(&ptr);`.

Output may print 5, may print 42, may crash.  It is UB.

> ... correct that the memory of the stack should be completely wiped out

No.  There is not specified wiping of memory.  The result is UB.

> But sometimes undefined behavior works?

"undefined behavior" is *undefined*.  Even if it "works" today, it may not "work" tomorrow.

> When we declare a, the memory allocated is put onto the stack frame; thus, when leaving the local scope of the function that memory is deleted and the frame is popped off of the stack.

This *assumes* an underling code model that is not specified by C.  Other real possibilities exist.

> How can we still access that variable `a` with the `ptr` variable in the main function?

As is, no defined way.  Alternatively keep the address of `a` valid by making `a` `static`.

Answer (score 0):

In `Foo` function, we are updating the address of our pointer. `int a` declared in `foo` function will be stored at some memory location. Now, we are assigning that location to our ptr(which is okay, ptr can point to any memory location of type `int`). But the issue is the value at that location is not in our control and this location can be used for any other purpose which may update the value at that location.

It means that our pointer is now pointing to location that may be updated by any other source.